# why my submit button's not working in updateview in Django?

Tags: django

When I click on submit button it goes nowhere and does nothing. Can you spot me the mistake?
I want to update on `department` field and `year` field. Also I'm using `MultiSelectField` from `django-multiselectfield` third party. The form shows up correctly except submit button's not working.

here is my models.py

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    type_choice = (('Full Time', _('Full Time')), ('Part Time', _('Part Time')))
    departments = (
            ('TC', 'Foundation Year'), ('GIC', 'Software Engineering'),
            ('GEE', 'Electrical Engineering'), ('GIM', 'Mechanical Engineering'),
            ('OAC', 'Architecture'), ('OTR', 'Telecom'), ('GCI', 'Civil Engineering'),
            ('GGG', 'Geotechnical Engineering'), ('GRU', 'Rural Engineering')
    ) 
    years = (
        ('year1', 'Year1'), ('year2', 'Year2'), ('year3', 'Year3'),
        ('year4', 'Year4'), ('year5', 'Year5')
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    teacher_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=type_choice)
    department = MultiSelectField(choices=departments)
    year = MultiSelectField(choices=years)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.user.email, self.teacher_type)
```

forms.py

```
class TeacherForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ['teacher_type', 'department', 'year']
```

views.py

```
@method_decorator(teacher_required, name="dispatch")
class TeacherDepartEditView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Teacher
    login_url = "/"
    form_class = TeacherForm
    template_name = "attendance/content/teacher/teacher_dep_edit.html"

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('teacher_info')
```

template

```
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>Choose department ( can choose more than one )</label>
      {{ form.department}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>Choose Year ( can choose more than one )</label>
      {{ form.year }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-cyan" type="submit" > Edit </button>     
</form>
```

here is the urls.py for the update view

```
path('teacher-info/<int:pk>/dep-update/', TeacherDepartEditView.as_view(), name="teacher_dep_update")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it's not working is because in my `TeacherForm` I have specified 3 field `teacher_type`, `department`, `year` but in my template i only included 2 fields which are `{{ form.department }}` and `{{ form.year }}`. I fixed it by just adding another field to the template which is `{{ form.teacher_type }}`.